# maven profile conditional dependency

Tags: maven

I have a pom file where I have 1 conditional dependency and a number of other dependencies which are not conditional (i.e. I want those dependencies to exist for both profiles).

The condition is whether or not I am deploying on tomcat or websphere so I have named my maven profiles accordingly.

My question is how can I make just that single dependency conditional based on my profile and the other dependencies exist for both profiles?

I had a shot at it and have pasted what I have attempted below but what I have doesn't seem to be working. Would welcome some feedback.

thanks

```
<!-- tried to put the conditional dependencies in the profile section -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>tomcat</id>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>        
    </profile>
    <profile>
     <id>websphere</id>
     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     </dependencyManagement>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<!-- then list all other non-conditional dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Which one you want to make a available for both profiles? Why not to put it in *non-conditional dependencies*?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by doesn't seem to be working? You have 2 profiles so depending upon profile dependency should have get picked up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't really have dependency management sections in your profiles. Dependency management is for creating a list of dependencies with defaulted versions that you reference in your module's dependency sections. You want to have a dependency section in your profiles. The common dependencies used on both servers should be listed in the top-level dependencies section.

However, this is still a bad pattern, because you can't promote a single build between environments. It would be better if you make the container dependent dependencies `provided` scope, then have the library deployed to the sever separately.

Also, I'm assuming that the code you have here is just for demonstration purposes, because the jstl dependency is the same on both containers.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a great answer. I have changed the xml so as just to have the dependency tag as children of the profile tag rather than the dependency management tags and removed the dependency management tags. Even though the jstl dependency is the same for websphere the scope is provided but for tomcat it is not and hence I tried to find a solution to this using maven profiles. And thanks to yourself it works well.

Comment: oh and also regarding your note about not being able to promote the build through environments. We are using tomcat for local builds but websphere for prod builds. Luckily for websphere we have multiple non-prod environments to promote the websphere build through before it goes to prod.